# How can I scaffold a new Nim project?

Tags: nim-lang

Languages like Rust have Cargo which among other things is used to scaffold a new project by calling `cargo new <project-name>`. Is there a similar tool or command in Nim language that can be used to scaffold a new project? Something in the line of `<some-command> new <project-name>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nimble](https://github.com/nim-lang/nimble) is the package manager for Nim, and it has been bundled together with Nim since Nim 0.15.0 (as of this writing, Nim is at v1.0.6, while Nimble is still in beta at v0.11.0). Nimble allows you to create library packages, binary packages, or hybrid packages, specify dependencies, licensing, etc., and creates a minimal directory structure for you.

Executing `nimble init` from the command line in your project directory will cause Nimble to ask you a series of questions; the answers are used to create a `.nimble` file in your project directory, and a minimal suitable directory structure. The Nimble docs provide more details about [how the `init` command is used to create packages.](https://github.com/nim-lang/nimble#creating-packages)